# how to compare values on different screen in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I want to get value of ref_no from page1 by locating it using name=ref_no. Now i clicked submit and another page opened which again show ref_no.
I want to compare these.
note: these are in 2 different "User Keyword"

In 1st user keyword, i am using:

```
${tmp}  Get Text    name=ref_no
Set Global Variable ${ref_no}   ${tmp}
```

In 2nd user keyword, i am using:

```
${ref_no_again} Get Text    name=ref_no
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${ref_no}   ${ref_no_again}
```

This is giving error. How to do this.

Comment: have you added some logging to determine you're pulling back the values you expect?

You seem to be doing the right thing to me, what is the error given?

Comment: Even before running testcase, in 2nd user keyword ${ref_no} is shown in pink color, whereas all other show in green. when i took cursor over it, it showed "Argument: first unknown variable". So suppose ref_no is 1234, i am getting this error !=1234 ie it is not reading value of ref_no. But when i log value of ref_no in 1st user keyword, it shows correctly as 1234.

Comment: Make sure there is no ${ref_no} defined elsewhere. What you are doing looks right.

Comment: I think, in 1st user keyword, i am not able to extract text value. It is a input box. I hope "Get Text" is correct to get text from input box.

Comment: if you try to log ${tmp} before you set it as a global variable, does it contain the value you expect?  Using Get Text shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: no, it is still blank. Unique ref_no is generated everytime i refresh the page. So, when page opens, initially it is blank and after 1 sec it gets the value. Although i am reading value after it appears, but still getting blank value.

Comment: how are you ensuring it is there?  Sounds like a timing issue to me